# How to deal with a GET variable of 'name'?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, urls

I'd like to have a custom registration confirmation page live within a WordPress site. I can provide a URL for this page to an external site. When the registration is successful the URL has several parameters, one of which is 'name' (which of course is a reserved word in WordPress) and a 404/page not found results.

The URL (get variables are coming from an external site, so I have no control over them) is something like:

```
http://example.com/registration-complete/?UID=K2PRL04LFYFNPY9&name=John&PIN=408446&conferenceUID=BYNMY9GILMCJWOBG&role=PARTICIPANT
```

What is the best way to handle such a situation? I'd like to be able to use the 'name' value in the page, so I don't want to just discard.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If it is a parameter in the query, then `$_GET` should work fine.

Comment: The page never loads (404) because 'name' is a reserved word in WordPress. For all the other terms $_GET will work fine.

Comment: Can you control this URL? I guess you'll have to change name to something else. Here's a list of what terms are reserved in WP universe: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms
Use anything apart from these!

Comment: As mentioned in the original post: "get variables are coming from an external site, so I have no control over them"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it's useful for someone else in this situation, I ended up creating a page outside WordPress which renames the 'name' parameter (to 'username') and then redirects to the page I originally wanted to hit.

My code for this external page is:

```
<?php
$data = array('UID' => $_GET['UID'],
    'username' => $_GET['name'],
    'ANI' => $_GET['ANI'],
    'PIN' => $_GET['PIN'],
    'conferenceUID' => $_GET['conferenceUID'],
    'role' => $_GET['role'],
    'email' => $_GET['email'],
    'notes' => $_GET['notes'],
    'custom2' => $_GET['custom2'],
    'custom1' => $_GET['custom1'],
    'inboundAccessID' => $_GET['inboundAccessID'],
    'time_created' => $_GET['time_created'],
    'callinNumber' => $_GET['callinNumber']);

header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/registration-complete/?'.http_build_query($data) ) ;
?>
```